# send post request to firebase cloud messaging by ajax error

Tags: javascript, jquery, api, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I want to send the remote push notification to an ios app in firebase console everything is ok and I can send a remote notification successfully. But I want to use ajax request in my web cms to send a notification but it gives 401 error

Ajax request:

```
InfoData = {
  "message":{
    "token" : "device token",
    "notification" : {
      "body" : "This is an FCM notification message!",
      "title" : "FCM Message",
      }
   }
}

$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: 'https://fcm.googleapis.com/v1/projects/Project ID/messages:send',
        ContentType: 'application/json',
        headers : {

          Authorization : 'key=' + 'Web API Key'

      },
        data: InfoData,
        datatype: "html",
        success: function(result){
            console.log(result);
        }
    });
```

and console show jquery-1.9.1.min.js:5 POST https://fcm.googleapis.com/v1/projects/sefrtasad-2e4d5/messages:send 401 ()

[image]

web cms language is PHP

what did I wrong?
is there any example to do this?

Comment: There seems to be no docs from Google on using this service other than some light examples using Node which seems to be different with everything else. It's really frustrating. I think you need a bearer token. Open up the error and see what it's telling you exactly. I've been working on this exact same thing for months. Us web guys don't get much help if we aren't using Node, we aren't liked.